# 403 Forbidden when trying to create a JSS app

Tags: jss

[image]

I'm facing this issue when trying to create my first JSS react app. That's weird because I have other members on my team who are able to make it work even if we have pretty much the same setup (or at least we think we have).

```
Server sent 403 Forbidden while enumerating templates.
```

I'm almost sure that this command is trying to reach the **JSS GitHub repository** to fetch the JSS react templates. So I'm guessing that's where I'm getting my `403 forbidden` from.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a 403 is being received when `jss create` tries to connect to the JSS GitHub repo to retrieve the react (or Vue, Angular, etc...) sample app. So either some service between you and github.com is responding with a 403 or github.com is sending you a 403.

A couple suggestions:

- Ensure that you are not restricted from accessing github.com due to firewall / proxy rules.
- Try "manually" requesting `https://api.github.com/repos/sitecore/jss/contents/samples?ref=master` (via browser, Postman, etc..). GitHub may return an error message that can help you troubleshoot. For example

  > API rate limit exceeded for xx.xx.xxx.xxx.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Adam. Status update: When I try the exact same command using Git Bash instead of Cmd everything works fine :surprised:

Comment: Another status update: No error when calling `https://api.github.com/repos/sitecore/jss/contents/samples?ref=master` in my browser and I have full access to github.com from my machine. It's something related to the cmd prompt since it's working when using Git Bash.